# Prove there exists a self-adjoint transformation $C$ s.t. $CA=B$ if $A$ and $AB$ are self adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations such that $A$ and $AB$ are self adjoint and such that $\ker (A)\subset \ker (B)$, then prove there exists a self-adjoint transformation $C$ s.t. $CA=B$.

Answer (score 3):

1. If $\text{ker}(A)\subset\text{ker}(B)$ then $\text{im}(B^*)\subset\text{im}(A^*)$, that is 
   $$
   \forall x\ \exists y_x\colon \ B^*x=A^*y_x.
   $$
   Taking $x=e_k$ and introducing $C^*=[y_{e_1}\ y_{e_2}\ldots y_{e_n}]$ we get $B^*=A^*C^*$ $\Leftrightarrow$  $CA=B$.
2. Since $A$ is self-adjoint, we can diagonalize it by a unitary $U$ for simplicity.
   $$
   D=U^*AU.
   $$
   Introduce also $\tilde B=U^*BU$ and $\tilde C=U^*CU$. Then 
   $$
   CA=B\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
   \left[\matrix{\tilde C_1 & \tilde C_2\\\tilde C_3 & \tilde C_4}\right]
   \left[\matrix{D_1 & 0\\0 & 0}\right]=\left[\matrix{\tilde B_1 & \tilde B_2\\\tilde B_3 & \tilde B_4}\right]
   $$
   where $D_1$ is invertible (collecting non-zero eigenvalues of $A$).
3. Nothing depends on the blocks $\tilde C_2$ and $\tilde C_4$ (multiplied by zero blocks), so we can change them to $\tilde C_2=\tilde C_3^*$ and $\tilde C_4=0$. Further, 
   $$
   \tilde C_1 D_1=\tilde B_1\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad
   \tilde C_1 =\tilde B_1D_1^{-1}=D_1^{-1}\underbrace{(D_1\tilde B_1)}_{\text{self-adjoint}}D_1^{-1}=\tilde C_1^*.
   $$
   Finally, pick
   $$
   C=U\left[\matrix{\tilde C_1 & \tilde C_3^*\\\tilde C_3 & 0}\right]U^*.
   $$